# Many errors with Mapbox

Tags: android, mapbox

I try to connect my app with Mapbox. I think I did everything correctly but there is a problem and I don't know what should I do

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.softwareclinics.driver, PID: 9114
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.softwareclinics.driver/com.softwareclinics.driver.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in com.softwareclinics.driver:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #17 in com.softwareclinics.driver:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3356)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3500)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2049)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in com.softwareclinics.driver:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #17 in com.softwareclinics.driver:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in com.softwareclinics.driver:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.softwareclinics.driver.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7973)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3329)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3500)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2049)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
    Caused by: com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.exceptions.MapboxConfigurationException: 
    Using MapView requires calling Mapbox.getInstance(Context context, String accessToken) before inflating or creating the view. The access token parameter is required when using a Mapbox service.
    Please see https://www.mapbox.com/help/create-api-access-token/ to learn how to create one.
    More information in this guide https://www.mapbox.com/help/first-steps-android-sdk/#access-tokens.
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView.initialize(MapView.java:136)
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView.(MapView.java:112)
            ... 30 more
```

I'm sorry for my bad English. Thank you for your help.

Comment: "Using MapView requires calling Mapbox.getInstance(Context context, String accessToken) before inflating or creating the view. The access token parameter is required when using a Mapbox service." Did you read the error? :) Did you call `Mapbox.getInstance()`?

Answer (score 0):

Mapbox.getInstance() doesn't work for me

try this to your mapview xml  file

app:mapbox_resourcesAccessToken="@string/MapsToken"

```
<com.mapbox.maps.MapView xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLat="40.7128"
    mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLng="-74.0060"
    app:mapbox_resourcesAccessToken="@string/MapsToken"
    mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="9.0" />
```